# Determine if bases for R2 and R3 exist, given a linear transformation matrix with respect to said bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know how to approach finding a matrix of a linear transformation with respect to bases, but I am stumped as to how to approach this in the case of 'determining' and 'proving' whether or not 2 bases $\mathscr C_2$ and $\mathscr C_3$ exist for $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, respectively

The linear transformation *T* : $\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ in question is defined by
*T*$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 2x + y \\ y + 2z\end{pmatrix}$

Where the matrix of T with respect to $\mathscr C_3$ and $\mathscr C_2$ is given as

$Matrix_{\mathscr C_3,\mathscr C_2}$(*T*) = $\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So you want the matrix representation of the linear transformation $T$, assuming the standard basis in each space? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Arthur, I think what they want is to find bases of $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ such that the matrix of the given transformation equals $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ with respect to those bases.

Comment: @memerson That seems more reasonable than my suggestion, now that you say it.

Comment: Yes, I already have the matrix representation. The bases $\mathscr C_3$ and $\mathscr C_2$ are to be found (if they exist), where the matrix representation of the transformation *T* with respect to those bases is given

Comment: You can _always_ find bases for which the matrix has some number of $1$s along the main diagonal and the rest of the matrix is zero. That’s a consequence of the rank-nullity theorem. The key to this solving this problem is determining how many $1$s there should be for $T$.

Comment: @amd Can you elaborate on this? If the matrix of T is diagonal, how does that relate to the rank-nullity theorem? Is it because the columns are linearly independent? I can see that now that you have pointed it out but im jot sure what you mean by "how many 1s there should br for *T*"

Comment: I didn’t say that the matrix is diagonal. That’s obviously impossible when the vectors spaces have different dimensions. It has some number of columns that each consist of a single $1$ and zeros otherwise, and the rest of its columns are all zero. Think about how the number of zero and nonzero columns relate to the rank and nullity of $T$.

Comment: @amd Ah yes, of course, I didn't consider that the matrix was non square (I know why it is not, though). If there are 2 non-zero columns and 1 zero column, does that mean the rank and nullity of *T* are 2 and 1 respectively?

Comment: As long as the nonzero columns are linearly independent, yes. So, does the rank of $T$ match the rank of the given matrix?

Comment: @amd The rank of the matrix is 2, since the first 2 columns are linearly independent and, if the dimension of the image of *T* is also 2 then the rank of T matches that of its matrix? I see from the definition of the matrix of a transformation *T* that the columns are linear combos of the elements in the basis $\mathscr C_2$, the combo being equal to *T* of each element in $\mathscr C_3$. If I assume that $\mathscr C_3$={a,b,c} & $\mathscr C_2$={d,e}, would I be correct in saying that *T*(a) = {2a,0} = {d,0} => d = 2a, similary *T*(b) => b = e = 0, *T*(c) => c = 0? Or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for any linear map $T:V\to W$ with $V$ and $W$ finite-dimensional, you can always find a pair of bases such that the $\dim W\times\dim V$ matrix of $T$ has the form $$\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I_r & 0 \\ \hline 0&0\end{array}\right],$$ where $r=\operatorname{rank}T$. This is a consequence of the rank-nullity theorem. The proof gives you a way to construct these bases: With $n=\dim V$ and $m=\dim W$, let $\{v_r,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $\ker T$. Extend this to a complete basis for $V$. The vectors $w_1=Tv_1,\dots,w_{r-1}=Tv_{r-1}$ are distinct and linearly independent (why?), so they form a basis for the image of $T$. Extend this to a complete basis of $W$. The matrix relative to these bases then has the desired form.

So, if the only thing that this problem asks you to do is to verify that such bases exist, all you need to do is compare the rank of $T$ to the rank of the given matrix. The latter is obviously 2, so is $\operatorname{rank}T$ also equal to 2? If you also have to produce a pair of bases, the above procedure tells you how to find such a pair. If you’re dealing with real vector spaces, it should be clear from the construction that there’s an infinite number of basis pairs that work.

Comment: I can see why that would be the case, since the number of lin. indep. columns in the identity is equal to the rank of T. Are the vectors $w_1$ = *T* $v_1$,...,$w_{r-1} = *T* $v_{r-1}$ linearly independent because the transformation matrix is defined as the identity? i.e. the linear combo of the w basis vectors only has 1 non-zero co-efficient? Also, the questions *specifically* asks to determine if the bases $\mathscr C_3$ and $\mathscr C_2$ could exist as bases for $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$, respectively. How would one prove this?

Comment: @nrg1998 The above _is_ a constructive proof that those bases exist. As for why the $Tv_i$ are linearly independent, proving that is usually given as an exercise in linear algebra courses. You should try to prove it for yourself (hint: try proof by contradiction). It’s not to do with the form of the matrix because you don’t have the matrix yet—that argument would be circular.